# Sort MMM-yyyy in List without converting to Date

Tags: java

How could I sort the monthYear list without converting the string into Date object? I am not able to apply the logic here.

```
public class SortDates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] monthName = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL",
                "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

        List<String> monthYear = new ArrayList<String>();

        monthYear.add("JAN-1999");
        monthYear.add("JUN-2009");
        monthYear.add("MAR-2003");
        monthYear.add("JAN-1998");
        monthYear.add("NOV-2013");

    }

}
```

Comment: you need to write your own Comparator

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the obvious step of converting these into at least a year/month structure? I'm sure it's doable with just string operations, but it's ugly compared with actually parsing.

Comment: Lord, forgive me all my offences, 

I need to sort a huge list which has these values coming in string format and in MMM-yyyy format. I want to avoid the steps of converting the string into date and comparing it and then converting back to string. 

I ask pardon from Thee for my ignorance

Comment: Why would creating a Date list, adding each item to the list as a Date them running a sort on the list be such a horrible thing?

Comment: You wouldn't have to convert back to a string. Create a map date-->string, sort the keyset, return the values.

Answer (score 3):

I would first describe  the months in an enum:

```
enum Month{ JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC };
```

Then you can easily implement your own comparator:

```
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
  @Override
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

    //If s1="JAN-1999", parts1[0]="JAN", parts1[1]="1999"
    String[] parts1=s1.split("-");
    //Month.valueOf("JAN") converts "JAN" to Month.JAN
    int m1 = Month.valueOf(parts1[0]).ordinal();
    int year1 = Integer.valueOf(parts1[1]);

    String[] parts2=s2.split("-");
    int m2 = Month.valueOf(parts2[0]).ordinal();
    int year2 = Integer.valueOf(parts2[1]);

    return ...//Here, compare year1 to year2 and if necessary, m1 and m2
    //You can also return (100*year2+m2) - (100*year1+m1)
  }
}
```

Then use it to sort :

```
Collections.sort(monthYear, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: Enums and strings have their own comparator, so you can use `parts1[1].compareTo(parts2[1])` and `Month.valueOf(parts1[0]).compareTo(Month.valueOf(parts2[0])`

Comment: That's right for enums but it is dangerous for years as "1000" < "700".

Comment: With this approach, you're parsing the same string every time a comparison is made.

Comment: true :) But if it makes the application go really slow, it will be still time to optimize : `premature optimization is the root of all evil`. Depending on the size of the list, it might make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.sort(List<T> list,Comparator<? super T> c)`

and specify your own comparator to parse those strings. [See the doc for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

*However*, I would recommend converting to dates by parsing them using `SimpleDateFormat`, and *strongly* recommend actually storing them as dates, since that's what they really are. Currently your solution is *stringly* typed - I would prefer *strongly* typed since your compiler can work to verify what you're doing.

Comment: In your comparator you can split monthDate on the dash and then compare the year as an int first, and then the month as a string.

Comment: @ChadCook If you're taking this route, you might as well compare the years as strings instead of parsing them to ints.

Answer (score 0):

WHat about mapping the month with their numeric value?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("JAN", 1);
...
```

and then check that?